# What to prefer sync / async S3 when uploading multiple files at once [Java]

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have to store maximum 10 images[Each image size is 2 MB] to S3. As S3 cannot store multiple images at once in a single API call, I need to call putObject 10 times sequentially. My question is, do i have to prefer async call or sync ?

Im assuming that sync will work in this scenario because S3 handles 3500 requests per second & each image size will be 2 MB. So i don't think i will face latency issues in my application.

Comment: The answer to this question is really up to your application. If the images are a time-lined story and it wouldn't make sense to upload the 5th image without uploading the 4th, then you should go by sync (so you can wait for success of each image before moving to next). If the order is unimportant, then async would be more efficient and even if you happen to five image 5th loaded without image 4th, you wouldn't mind.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My application don't require any order. But it needs the confirmation that images got stored successfully. If all images are stored then it should proceed with next steps.  But my main concern is will it cause any latency

Comment: I don't know specifically the Amazon-S3 but generally speaking, if you post a sync request it will be up to the server to release the handle when it's done whereas if you post the async request, the server will call you back when the result is ready and you can meanwhile do other things. If you need to wait for the confirmation, you can post them asynchronously and then wait for the 10 to have the confirmation callback